Gmail add-on exception: Access token does not specify a valid thread
We have a Gmail add-on and one of our users encountered one weird issue, the error message is:
Exception: Access denied: : Access token does not specify a valid thread: cloud_project_number: xxxx
when the code get thread messages by [GmailMessage object].getThread().getMessages().

The add-on works fine for all other users, both on web Gmail and iPhone Gmail app
For that specific user, the add-on works fine from web Gmail, the only problem is on his iPhone Gmail app

So we have no idea why the same code doesn't work only for this user on his iphone, from what we know, it worked on his old iphone, but only had this issue after he changed to the new iPhone.
I think this error is not related to the scopes as it works for other users, we also tested on the same iPhone model with the same version of the Gmail app and all worked, so not sure what happened on his iphone.
Please help.
